# accessing to the backend from a subdomain in laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, laravel-5, subdomain, hosting

I am using laravel for crud and cms purposes. I have a frontend and backend. Both backend and frontend is loading from the public folder.

From the Cpanel I have pointed my domain to the public folder. So, the website is loading when I type `www.site.com` and the backend is loading after login verification when I type `www.site.com/dashboard`

I would like to seperate my backend from the frontend. I would like to access to the backend from the url `admin.site.com` or `cms.site.com` and I would like to access to the front end from the url `www.site.com`.

How can I manage to do this? I can point the subdomain to the public folder as well and can load the backand from the url `cms.site.com/dashboard` but the backend still would be accessible from the url `www.site.com/dashboard`.

I would appreciate if you can give me an idea about seperating the frontend from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have a separate controller to handle back-end and that controller's index method returns the back-end view. In that case you can use Laravel's subdomain routing function to route your sub-domain to your backend site.
like this

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.site.com'], function () {

   Route::get('/', 'backendController@index');

})
```

or If you don't have a controller and just have a view to be displayed

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'admin.site.com'], function () {
   Route::get("/", function(){
          return View::make("backend_view");
    });
})
```

Note: `backend_view` refers to a `backend_view.blade.php` in your `resources/views` folder.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try this.